# Random effect Estimate in SAS

Tags: sas, random-effects

I have a panel data of firms (Panel specification: ID,Time) and trying to run Logit Random Effect model on this data in SAS where my binary (0,1) dependent variable is Def. This is the code that I am using:

```
PROC GLIMMIX DATA=mydata METHOD=QUAD(QPOINTS=21) NOCLPRINT;
CLASS ID;
MODEL Def (DESC) = VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4/SOLUTION DIST=BINARY LINK=LOGIT;
RANDOM INTERCEPT / SUBJECT=ID;
RUN;
```

When I run the code, in the output the only table that I get for the coefficient estimates is called: Solutions for Fixed Effects. My question is that where are the coefficient estimates for random effect? How can I get those estimates in output?

Thanks for your help in advance.
Sei

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `SOLUTION` option to the `RANDOM` statement as well.

```
RANDOM INTERCEPT / SUBJECT=ID SOLUTION;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aniko. I tried this option but I get the "Solution for Random Effect" table which only contains the coefficient for each Subjects. I still don't get any coefficient estimate for the independent variables? For the independent variables coefficients It outputs the table "Solution for Fixed Effects", like how it did before as well!

Comment: Your model does not have random effects for the independent variables in the model: you explicitly have only a random intercept. You need to add the effects that you would like to be random to the `RANDOM` statement.